# How to push values to property array in Cypher?

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes `user` and `files` with a relationship `:contains`, the relationship has a property `id`which is an array, represented as

```
(:user)-[:contains{id:[12345]}]->(:files)
```

However I want to populate the property array `id` with values `1111` and `14567` **sequentially** using `Cypher` queries, I dont find any method to push values into the array.

After inserting 1111 to property `id` it will be:

```
(:user)-[:contains{id:[12345,1111]}]->(:files)
```

After inserting 14567 to property `id` it will be:

```
(:user)-[:contains{id:[12345,1111,14567]}]->(:files)
```

I don't know how to populate values to an property array sequentially.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Adding values to an array is analogous to incrementing an integer or concatenating a string and is signified the same way, in your case (let `c` be your `[c:contains {id:[12345]}]`)

```
c.id = c.id + 1111             //  [12345,1111]
c.id = c.id + 14567            //  [12345,1111,14567]
```

or

```
c.id = c.id + [1111,14567]     //  [12345,1111,14567]
```

Comment: How to handle possibly null values?

Comment: @MichaelCole Did you find an answer for null values?

Comment: @MichaelCole use either coalesce or CASE

Answer (score 17):

**If one of the attribute is null** (which could result in horrible errors):

`SET n.id = coalesce(n.id, []) + n.additionalId`

The coalesce goes through the comma seperated list (inside the round brackets) from left to right and skips the variables that are `Null` values.
So in this case if `n.id` is initially `Null` the coalesce would take the second parameter which is the empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

full query for newbies

```
MATCH (a:Application {name:'A'})-[r:REQUEST_TO]-(d:Application {name:'B'})
WHERE ID(r) = 684
SET r.id = r.id + 'New Id'
```